# Smoothness over complete discrete valuation rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a complete discrete valuation ring with uniformizer $\pi$.
Let $f:X\to \mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} R$ be a morphism of finite type and assume that the smooth 
locus of $f$ contains every $x\in X$ with $f(x)=(\pi)$. Is $f$ necessarily 
smooth?

Note that the assumption on the smooth locus is equivalent to the assumption 
that the base change of $f$ with respect to $R\to R/(\pi^n)$ is smooth for every 
$n\in\mathbb{N}$ (use Proposition 17.14.2 in EGA IV which states that
it suffices to verify the infinitesimal lifting criterion with local Artin rings as test objects).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Take $f:X\rightarrow\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ such that $X_0:=X\times_R K$, $K=\mathrm{Frac}(R)$,  possesses at least one singularity and there exists a point $x\in X\times_R R/(\pi)$ at which $f$ is smooth. Then there exists an (affine) open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ on $X$ such that $f$ is smooth at every $y\in U$. Since $X_0$ is open in $X$, the open subscheme $X_0\cup U$ is a counterexample to your conjecture.

Comment: Okay, that's embarrassing. I didn't even ask for the special fiber to be non-empty, so any non-smooth scheme of finite type over $K$ will do. Argh. Thank you.

Comment: Well, you could require $f$ to be closed ...